# Dynamic data source in Terraform 12

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform0.12+

I'm creating alerts ([azurerm_monitor_scheduled_query_rules_alert](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/monitor_scheduled_query_rules_alert.html)) in Azure using Terraform. You can include a list of action groups (i.e. the groups that you send the alerts to).

Within the TFVars file I will pass in a variable value of a list of the names of the action groups. However, the alert module needs the ID's of the resources, not the names. So I have a data source that would get the info of an action group. The Alert resource can then refer to the data source to acquire the azure resource id.

This works fine if I have just one action group, but the size of the list with action group names can vary. I'm trying to figure out how I can convert all action group names to id for ingestion by the resource.

```
resource "azurerm_monitor_scheduled_query_rules_alert" "tfTestAlertExample" {
for_each = {for alert in var.scheduled_query_alerts : alert.name => alert}

  name                = each.value["name"]
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name

  action {

    # --This part here. How do I get make this dynamic?--
    action_group           = [
      data.azurerm_monitor_action_group.action_group.id
    ] 

    email_subject          = each.value["email_subject"]
    custom_webhook_payload = "{}"
  }

  data_source_id = ................ etc
```

So in the above example, there will only be one action{} block, but the Action_group list within that needs to be dynamic, with ID's retrieved from a data source. Or maybe there's another way of doing this that I've not considered.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: `action_group  =       data.azurerm_monitor_action_group.action_group.*.id` or `action_group  =       data.azurerm_monitor_action_group.action_group[*].id`?

Comment: That'd be good but the problem is the conversion of name to id. Not sure if I can have a data source resource that is dynamic.

Comment: So you want to filter your data source based on group names?

Comment: i.e. it might be that I have 3 action groups, or maybe 2. How do I retrieve the IDs for each of these from a dynamic list

Comment: Yeah. I have the names in a list variable. These need to then be "converted" to ID.

Comment: You can have data source dynamic. Just use `for_each` and then fetch IDs in the resource.

Comment: Is this issue fixed on your side?

Comment: @rkm Thanks. Yeah, the for_each helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to convert the list of action group names to its Ids, you can do it like this:

```
# declare the variables
variable "action_group_names" {
  default = ["nancyAG1","nancyAG2"]
}

# retrieve the Id of action group
data "azurerm_monitor_action_group" "example" {
  count = length(var.action_group_names)
  resource_group_name = "existingRG"
  name                = element(var.action_group_names,count.index)
}

# output the result to the terminal
output "groups_id" {
  value = data.azurerm_monitor_action_group.example[*].id
  
}
```

Then pass Ids to the resource like this:

```
resource "azurerm_monitor_scheduled_query_rules_alert" "example" {
  name                = format("%s-queryrule", var.prefix)
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  action {
    action_group           = data.azurerm_monitor_action_group.example[*].id
    email_subject          = "Email Header"
    custom_webhook_payload = "{}"
  }
```

Check the action_group Ids.

[image]

Comment: I ended up doing something similar using for_each (as suggested by @rkm) instead of count, but otherwise pretty much like your example. Thanks :)